# Вывести определённую строку из файла

Tags: python, файловый-ввод-вывод

```
file = 'f.txt'
myfile = open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf_8')
if file:
    print(myfile.readlines())
```

есть такой код, он открывает текстовый файл в котором номера телефонов и должен искать строку при вводе определённого номера но при этом он читает и отображает самую первую строку в независимости от того какой ввели номер, подскажите как сделать что бы при вводе номера показывало строку где содержится этот номер

Comment: да проверять наличие номера в строке надо

Comment: а вообще, это основа языка

Comment: Вроде ж этот код должен печатать весь файл

Comment: @CrazyElf видимо автор просто сам не до конца понимает, что делает/должен делать этот код

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```py
num = "56" # Искомый номер

# Читаем файл
with open("asd.txt", mode='r', encoding='utf_8') as f:
    lst = f.readlines()

# Ищем данные
for i in lst: # перебор всех элементов
    if num in i: # Проверка на наличие номера
        print(i)
```

Текстовый файл был составлен так:

```
12 qwe
21 asd
56 zxc
```

как понимаю что то вроде тел книги.

P.S. Если просто проверить наличие в номера в файле:

```py
num = "56"

with open("asd.txt", mode='r', encoding='utf_8') as f:
    lst = f.read()

if num in lst:
    print(num)
```

Comment: помогло спасибо

Comment: @Hugason дополнил если просто проверить наличие номера в файле. Нюанс что проверка верна если в файле есть 56 или например 156...

Answer (score 1):

```
file = 'f.txt'

myfile = open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf_8')
phones = myfile.read().splitlines() # можно .readlines(), но сохраняется '\n'

number = input()

if number in phones:
    print(number)
else:
    print('Nothing found')

myfile.close() # не забываем закрыть файл
```

Правильнее будет использовать конструкцию `with ... as ...`, которая за нас закроет файл, даже если выпадет исключение:

```
file = 'f.txt'

with open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf_8') as myfile:
    phones = myfile.read().splitlines() # можно .readlines(), но сохраняется '\n'

number = input()

if number in phones:
    print(number)
else:
    print('Nothing found')
```

Comment: Объяснение: при чтении файла с помощью метода `read()` мы получаем строку (string) с символами переноса строки, используя строковый метод `splitlines()`, мы разбиваем строку, по символам переноса строки в список, в итоге у нас есть список со всеми строками из файла. Соответсвенно если строка с введенным номером есть в списке строк, вместо того чтобы искать ее там можно просто вывести введенную строку.

Comment: Строка содержащая номер  не всегда равна номеру...

Comment: @Kers `текстовый файл в котором номера телефонов`. Даже если не всегда равна, то это надо прописывать в условии. Да и телефоны, будем честны, можно писать по разному. +7/8, x-xxx-xx-xxx-xx, x-(xxx)-..., xxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: помогло, но else отрабатывает как цикл и выводит если не нашёл отрицательный ответ для каждой строки

Comment: @Hugason вообще не должен, видимо вы запихнули конструкцию с if куда-то в цикл, делать этого не надо было

Comment: собственно в этом и суть, что мы экономим время не проходясь по всему файлу. Но, если у вас небольшая програмка, котрой без разницы исполниться этот фрагмент за 0.01 секунду или за 0.001, используйте код Kers'a